# Custom Parameter Type

Tags: c#-4.0

I have no clue where to find answers on Google how this is done.

In API's I see code that allows you to select specific values when calling a method.  Something like:

CallThisMethod(CustomAPITypes.SomeType1);
CallThisMethod(CustomAPITypes.SomeType2);

What is this called?  What do I need to google to find out more?

Comment: This (`CustomAPITypes.SomeType1`) looks like an enum because of the way it is used here.

Comment: that's it! thank you, add an answer if you want credit.